# Review of Competitive Physics: Jinhui Wang, Bernard Ricardo Part 1 and 2 for Physics Olympiads

Tags: education, specific-reference

I do have a copy of the book, which seems great. It was written by an Olympiad trainer and a student, which means it is related to Olympiads. But I never saw anyone mention the book. Is it any good for Olympiads?
https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/10817

Comment: This question will probably be closed soon for being opinion-based, but I personally have heard people speak highly of the Wang and Ricardo before.